# How many boundary conditions do we need to solve Laplace's equation?

Tags: electrostatics, voltage, gauss-law, boundary-conditions

I'm struggling to understand which boundary conditions are necessary to solve Laplace's equation. In order to better understand them, I have thought of a scenario that I would like to ask a couple of questions about. Suppose we have an electrode of shape defined by some arbitrary surface, $S$, at voltage $V$ relative to some ground, such that the electrode doesn't overlap with the origin. If I want to calculate the potential at the origin, I need to solve Poissons equation with appropriate boundary conditions.

My questions are:

1. Do we have to use the entire surface $S$ as a boundary condition, or is it sufficient to just use a set number of points?
2. Does the number of boundary conditions required change if the surface has appropriate symmetry conditions?
3. Does the number of boundary conditions required change if the electrode is far from the origin?
4. How does the number or choice of boundary conitions change upon addition of a second electrode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I have completely understood the setup of your question but here is an attempt to answer it (a drawing probably would help).

Let us assume that all your "boundaries" are ideal conducting surfaces but in between you have a vacuum. On an ideal conducting surface the tangential component of the electric intensity is zero, hence the potential is a constant on the surface but the constant maybe different for unconnected conducting surfaces. These surfaces must be piecewise smooth, and such smooth pieces in finite numbers to be at the same potential may also be joined continuously not necessarily smoothly meaning that there is no unique tangent to it.

1. specifying the potential at a finite set of discrete points is not enough
2. no it odes, having a symmetry condition simplifies the solution but the number of independently definable and to be defined surfaces are the same, be it symmetric or otherwise.
3. you may approximate the local potential near one surface and ignore the effect of another surface far away from it but that is an approximation which may or may not be valid.
4. adding another electrode will add one more surface with a prescribed constant voltage just like the others.

Comment: Note that in many circumstances one of your "boundaries" is at infinity;  I suspect this includes the sorts of situations that the OP has in mind.